# Universal link test: Could not extract required information for application links

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

Trying to configure Universal Links for iOS 9. I am using Apple's validation tool:

https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/

Everything is passing except I get `Action Required` for `Link to Application`. The message is: "`Could not extract required information for application links. Learn how to implement the recommended Universal Links.`" I have tried running the tool both from my desktop and from a device that I believe is properly configured. Universal Links are not working for me when I try them from Safari.

There is nothing in the [linked documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) that explicitly explains what this required information might be.

Comment: Could we see the URL you are validating? You could also try the validator at http://branch.io/resources/universal-links/ — it runs some additional checks that Apple's does not

Comment: It does pass the branch.io validation. I actually have universal linking working now too, though that validation test is still failing. Would rather not share the URL.

Comment: If the implementation is working, I wouldn't worry too much about the failing validation. Without a URL to debug, that's probably as far as we can go in any case :)

Comment: This problem started for me as well about a month ago without explanation. Previously had been working (no code changes). There's been no answer on the Apple Developer forums either.

Comment: Do you have the `apple-app-site-association` file on the root folder or on the `.well-known`? Having the same issue on `.well-known`

Comment: @PabloA. I tried both locations. Never passed the validation tool, have moved on, but if anyone figures out what this is about or if Apple changes the behavior of the tool, I'd be very curious.

Comment: @BenFlynn in my case, my OpenSSL wasn't properly set up for files on `.well-known` folder, but working fine for anything on root. But it's interesting that despite deep-linking is working fine for my app, Apple tool still shows some error... It would be useful to have more documentation from Apple about the validation tool and possible errors...

Comment: @jasonjwwilliams what did you do?

Comment: @sebastián-rojas It was a glitch at Apple near as I can tell. It started working as mysteriously as it had stopped.

Comment: @jasonjwwilliams still not workin here :(

Comment: I'm getting "Error no apps with domain entitlements" in the Extracted data column. Did you have this error, or is my error somewhere else? FWIW universal links work well on device. My paths look like this: "paths": ["/", "/movie/*"]

Comment: the branch io validator is at https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: I'm having the same issue, branch.io validation passes, but apple's does not. And universal links are working randomly on some devices and on the others not. It seems this got worse with iOS13. Any solutions?

Comment: still have to same issue too, apple validation show : Could not extract required information for Universal Links, but my universal work sometimes (ios13)

Answer (score 9):

What fixed it for me, is realizing that you must enter an actual URL in the validation tool, and not just the domain (root) >IF< your apple-app-site-association file specifies a sub-path.

In other words, if only part of your website redirects to an app, be sure to enter in the validation tool a URL that includes the subdomain!

[Spent all day figuring this out - LOL]

Comment: I've spent 2 days tearing my hair out over this! give that man an upvote

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was with the '#' symbol in the link.

While `apple-app-site-association` file has the wild card to any "/?/foo/*" links, "/a/foo/bar" will pass while "/#/foo/bar" will not